# How to print, lets say you have an input 35, then your output should be 30 + 5. Or 456, output should be 400+50+6

Tags: python, list, loops

I have tried this:

```
def place(n):
total = 1
value = 0
list1 = []
while (n != 0):
    rem = n % 10
    n = n//10
    value = total * rem
    list1.append(value)
    total = total * 10
print(list1)


n = int(input())
print(place(n))
```

But I am not sure how do I print the desired output iterating through the list.

Comment: So, iterate through the list backwards.  The position in the list is the power of ten you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `str.join` to merge all of the values into a single string after reversing the order and converting each value to a string.  You can use the `map` function to convert each of the values into a string and you can reverse a list by slicing it in reverse.

so...

```
list1 = [9, 50, 800]
list1 = list1[::-1]           # [800,50,9]
list1 = map(str, list1)       # ~ ["800", "50", "9"] 
list1 = " + ".join(list1)     # "800 + 50 + 9"
```

`" + ".join(map(str,list1[::-1]))`

for example:

```
def place(n):
    total = 1
    value = 0
    list1 = []
    while (n != 0):
        rem = n % 10
        n = n//10
        value = total * rem
        list1.append(value)
        total = total * 10
    return " + ".join(map(str,list1[::-1]))

n = int(input())
print(place(n))
```